# Combine Onclick into AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an onclick that works in an HTML file. I am trying to make it function inside an AJAX script.

```
<script src='https://www.btcsquawk.com/responsivevoice.js'></script>
  <input onclick='responsiveVoice.speak("Hello World");' type='button' value=' Play' />
```

And I have an AJAX piece in a script.js file that reads data properly such as:

```
    case 'chatLine':
            arr = [
                '<div class="chat chat-',params.id,' rounded"><span class="author">',params.price,
                ':</span><span class="text">',params.price,'</span><span class="time">',params.price,'</span></div>'];
```

I need to combine them both an basically take the params.price into

```
 responsiveVoice.speak("params.price");'
```

Answer (score 0):

Write a wrapper function around the responsiveVoice api and then modify your onclick to call your wrapping function.

—— modified

On your switch case when you encounter the chatLine, do AJAX call; parse response; call responsiveVoice method with response. And then if you want to display it just do a body.append or what not.

Comment: I am not trying to use the onclick anymore, trying to the function aspect into the AJAX

Comment: Can you define what you mean by AJAX? I don’t think Im clear on what you’re are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Currently case 'chatLine': is refreshing php page and pulling mysql data every few seconds or so. I am trying to make it trigger the responsiveVoice.speak and use the chatLine mySql data as the responsiveVoice.speak."content"